# How to render webform element in twig file template for HTML display

Tags: theming, webforms

I want to override the HTML display for webform submissions. So, I have copy this file "webform-submission.html.twig" in my template folder and rename it in: "webform-submission--testform--html.html.twig"

Now, how do i print every element of my webform? 
It is written in the file:

- Available variables:

  - - elements: An array of elements to display in view mode.
  - - webform_submission: The webform submission.
  - - webform: The webform.

I tried with {{ elements.surname }} but it doesn't work.

I also installed the TWIG module.